# create index on tables for mysql query that involves join,group/order-by,union and like

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is the explain output for the slow query that has 10's of `"copying to tmp table"` state in mysql processlist.

```
explain SELECT distinct
    (radgroupreply.groupname),
    count(distinct (radusergroup.username)) AS users
FROM
    radgroupreply
        LEFT JOIN
    radusergroup ON radgroupreply.groupname = radusergroup.groupname
WHERE
    (radgroupreply.groupname NOT LIKE 'FB-%' AND radgroupreply.groupname NOT LIKE '%Dropped%')
GROUP BY radgroupreply.groupname 
UNION SELECT distinct
    (radgroupcheck.groupname),
    count(distinct (radusergroup.username))
FROM
    radgroupcheck
        LEFT JOIN
    radusergroup ON radgroupcheck.groupname = radusergroup.groupname
WHERE
    (radgroupcheck.groupname NOT LIKE 'FB-%' AND radgroupcheck.groupname NOT LIKE '%Dropped%')
GROUP BY radgroupcheck.groupname
ORDER BY groupname asc;

+----+--------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table         | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | radgroupreply | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   456 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | radusergroup  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 10261 |                                              |
|  2 | UNION        | radgroupcheck | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   167 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | UNION        | radusergroup  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 10261 |                                              |
|NULL| UNION RESULT | <union1,2>    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  NULL | Using filesort                               |
+----+--------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I cant get my head around this query to create compound/single index and optimize since it has multiple joins, group by and like operations.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and not a function (on a column). Those parentheses are completely redundant. (I.e. `select distinct (c1), c2, ...` is the same as `select distinct c1, c2, ...`, which is the same as `select distinct c1, (c2), ...`.)

Comment: Is there an index on radusergroup.groupname?

Comment: You probably want index on radusergroup.groupname, radusergroup.username so it can also get the counts from the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three observations to get started.

1. The `select distinct` is unnecessary (the `group by` takes care of that).
2. The `left join`s are unnecessary (the `where` clauses turn them into inner joins).
3. The `UNION` should probably be `UNION ALL`.  I doubt you really want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

So, you can write the query as:

```
SELECT rr.groupname, count(distinct rg.username) AS users  
FROM radgroupreply rr JOIN
     radusergroup rg
     ON rr.groupname = rg.groupname                                                  
WHERE rr.groupname NOT LIKE 'FB-%' AND rr.groupname NOT LIKE '%Dropped%'
GROUP BY rr.groupname 
UNION ALL
SELECT rc.groupname, count(rg.username)
FROM radgroupcheck rc JOIN
     radusergroup rg
     ON rc.groupname = rg.groupname                                 
WHERE rc.groupname NOT LIKE 'FB-%' AND rc.groupname NOT LIKE '%Dropped%'
GROUP BY rc.groupname
ORDER BY groupname asc;
```

This query can take advantage of indexes on `radusergroup(groupname)`.  I am guessing an index on `rc(radusergroup)` would be used.

I would also advice you to remove the `DISTINCT` in `COUNT(DISTINCT)` if it is not necessary.